# Visual Studio windows Tile and cross questions

Tags: visual-studio

I've recently (about 3 months ago) started using Visual Studio 2017 Community, v15.6.2. Questions that stump me:

1) How do I get all my windows to be tiled and remain on-screen as I move from one window to the next? At the moment I could have two or more windows in the workspace. As soon as I click on one to work in it, the others disappear. Don't know how to fix it!

2) What is that cross that appears in the center of the workspace when I am busy moving windows around. Cross seems to have arrows and made up of blocks by the looks of it.

3) How do I get the Properties Window to be vertically tabbed on the rhs side of the workspace? i.e. if I click on the Properties tab the Properties window appears, else it is not visible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default only one code file is visible in VS. To see multiple code windows at once you can create several tab groups or float document  windows outside the IDE. Another option is to use my [Task Canvas](https://vlasovstudio.com/task-canvas/) extension - after you add code files or fragments to the Task Canvas window they are automatically tiled.

For the guide diamond and other window management options please refer to the [Customize window layouts in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-window-layouts-in-visual-studio) documentation.